# Oracle database by .NET classes

Tags: .net, database, oracle, ado.net

I am beginner in Oracle database system. As I noticed, it is possible to access and manipulate an Oracle database using .NET classes. ADO.NET (`ActiveX Data Objects`) is used to deal with MS SQL database and it exists by default (as I guess) in the `Microsoft .NET Framework Class Library`.

I would like to know if Oracle database .NET classes are also included by default in ADO.NET or do I need to install/configure it to start using it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would like to know if Oracle database .NET classes are also included by default in ADO.NET or do I need to install/configure it to start using it?

There is [System.Data.Oracle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oracleclient.aspx) in the BCL but it [was deprecated](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2009/06/15/system-data-oracleclient-update.aspx) in 2009 and should no longer be used because it might be removed in a future version of the framework. You should download and use the [ODP.NET](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/index-085163.html) provider from Oracle.

Comment: Does that mean that I do need to install `ODP.NET`also in the client machine (client user) in addition with .NET Framework.

Comment: You don't need to install anything. ODP.NET is a .NET assembly that you reference in your project and this assembly needs to be shipped along with your project.